# Get data using Select query in azure function app

Tags: c#, ado.net

In my function app I have an IF statement that launches a main part of code only if two variables are set to 1 and 0. These variables are flags stored in the Azure SQL Table. I have made a simple select query, however the variable values are always -1. How can I solve this problem? Here is my code:

```
conn.Open();
    int IsDatamartSynced, IsCubeProcessed;
    var select_for_IsDatamartSynced = "SELECT TOP (1) IsDatamartSynced FROM dbo.test";
    var select_for_IsCubeProcessed = "SELECT TOP (1) IsCubeProcessed FROM dbo.test";
    /*var text = "UPDATE SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader " + 
            "SET [Status] = 5  WHERE ShipDate < GetDate();";*/

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select_for_IsDatamartSynced, conn))
    {
        IsDatamartSynced = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        log.Info($"in using {IsDatamartSynced}");
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select_for_IsCubeProcessed, conn))
    {
        IsCubeProcessed = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        log.Info($"in using {IsCubeProcessed}");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the number of rows affected for statements that change data, or -1 for other types of queries (including `SELECT`).

Use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223677(v=vs.110).aspx) when you want to retrieve a value:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select_for_IsDatamartSynced, conn))
{
    IsDatamartSynced = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    log.Info($"in using {IsDatamartSynced}");
}
```